# Is it possible to alter the CSS of an iFrame?

Tags: css, iframe

I would like to add, remove, and adjust the CSS of iFrame. In particular I am looking to to this to Disqus comments which embeds their comments into an iFrame on the page.

If I am allowed to modify the CSS of an iFrame is the only risk that I am susceptible to them (in this case Disqus) updating the CSS classes and ID's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't.

You can edit it via JavaScript, but the iframe content and its parent need to be on the same domain, if not you will not be able to do it